# Product Flat Data indexing always keeps on Processing

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

I have tried all approaches from truncating to checking table alter permission under DB but the Product Flat Data indexing always say on Processing and required re-indexing anybody has any idea about to solve this.

Comment: Probably something crashed and the index process does not finish. Check the var/log folder for possible errors.

Comment: Clear var/locks/* files & reindex via ssh

Answer (score 1):

Errors with indexing are caught and not displayed if you re-index via the GUI.

If you re-index via command line, any errors will be displayed.

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex ...
```

If you've got a large number of products/store views/attributes - then it will be slower to build. You should reall,  test your store performance with it on and off, as it doesn't always provide a performance improvement.

Comment: Typo: Indexer.php -> indexer.php

Answer (score 0):

I have  this problem I created the file in the root and ran the following code and it worked

```
    <?php
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(0);
require_once './app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

$indexer="./shell/indexer.php";

if(file_exists($indexer))
{
                $idxlist=array("catalog_product_attribute",
                               "catalog_product_price",
                               "catalog_product_flat",
                               "catalog_category_flat",
                               "catalog_category_product",
                               "catalog_url",
                               "catalogsearch_fulltext",
                               "cataloginventory_stock");


        //reindex using magento command line
        foreach($idxlist as $idx)
        {
            echo "reindex $idx n ";
            exec("php shell/indexer.php --reindex $idx");
        }

}
```

Hope this will work for you too.